# Can not install MariaDB 10.1 because of libmysql18-error

Tags: apt, 16.10, mariadb

I am currently trying to install MariaDB 10.1 on my Ubuntu 16.10. Unfortunately, the installation results in an error when installing libmysql18.

I've followed https://www.linuxbabe.com/mariadb/install-mariadb-10-1-ubuntu14-04-15-10 (and also tried different mirrors from https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories), but installing always results in:

```
reichelt@reichelt-ThinkPad-T440s:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client
OK:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
OK:2 http://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease                                                                                                                             
OK:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates InRelease                                                                                                                  
OK:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports InRelease                                                                                                            
Holen:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security InRelease [102 kB]                                                                           
Holen:6 http://sgp1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu yakkety InRelease [3.129 B]                               
Holen:7 http://sgp1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages [5.601 B]
Holen:8 http://sgp1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 Packages [5.588 B]
Es wurden 116 kB in 1 s geholt (85,7 kB/s).
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Die folgenden zusätzlichen Pakete werden Installiert
  galera-3 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libjemalloc1 libmariadbclient18 libmysqlclient18 libmysqlclient20 mariadb-client-10.1 mariadb-client-core-10.1 mariadb-common mariadb-server-10.1
  mariadb-server-core-10.1 mysql-common socat
Vorgeschlagene Pakete:
  libmldbm-perl libnet-daemon-perl libsql-statement-perl libterm-readkey-perl mariadb-test tinyca
Die folgenden NEUEN Pakete werden installiert:
  galera-3 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libjemalloc1 libmariadbclient18 libmysqlclient18 libmysqlclient20 mariadb-client mariadb-client-10.1 mariadb-client-core-10.1 mariadb-common mariadb-server
  mariadb-server-10.1 mariadb-server-core-10.1 mysql-common socat
0 aktualisiert, 16 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
Es müssen noch 5.710 B von 22,8 MB an Archiven heruntergeladen werden.
Nach dieser Operation werden 193 MB Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n] j
Holen:1 http://sgp1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 mariadb-client all 10.1.21+maria-1~yakkety [2.792 B]
Holen:2 http://sgp1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 mariadb-server all 10.1.21+maria-1~yakkety [2.918 B]
Es wurden 5.710 B in 0 s geholt (6.717 B/s).
Vorkonfiguration der Pakete ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket mysql-common wird gewählt.
(Lese Datenbank ... 1213868 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../00-mysql-common_10.1.21+maria-1~yakkety_all.deb ...
Entpacken von mysql-common (10.1.21+maria-1~yakkety) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket mariadb-common wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../01-mariadb-common_10.1.21+maria-1~yakkety_all.deb ...
Entpacken von mariadb-common (10.1.21+maria-1~yakkety) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket galera-3 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../02-galera-3_25.3.19-yakkety_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von galera-3 (25.3.19-yakkety) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket libdbi-perl wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../03-libdbi-perl_1.636-1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von libdbi-perl (1.636-1) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket libmysqlclient20:amd64 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../04-libmysqlclient20_5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von libmysqlclient20:amd64 (5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.10.1) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket libdbd-mysql-perl wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../05-libdbd-mysql-perl_4.035-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von libdbd-mysql-perl (4.035-1ubuntu0.1) ...
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Archivs /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-F7lK7w/06-libmysqlclient18_10.1.21+maria-1~yakkety_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 libmysqlclient18:amd64 10.1.21+maria-1~yakkety (Multi-Arch: no) kann nicht zusammen mit libmysqlclient18 installiert werden, welches mehrere installierte Instanzen hat
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket libmariadbclient18 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../07-libmariadbclient18_10.1.21+maria-1~yakkety_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von libmariadbclient18 (10.1.21+maria-1~yakkety) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket mariadb-client-core-10.1 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../08-mariadb-client-core-10.1_10.1.21+maria-1~yakkety_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von mariadb-client-core-10.1 (10.1.21+maria-1~yakkety) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket mariadb-client-10.1 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../09-mariadb-client-10.1_10.1.21+maria-1~yakkety_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von mariadb-client-10.1 (10.1.21+maria-1~yakkety) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket libjemalloc1 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../10-libjemalloc1_3.6.0-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von libjemalloc1 (3.6.0-9ubuntu1) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket mariadb-server-core-10.1 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../11-mariadb-server-core-10.1_10.1.21+maria-1~yakkety_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von mariadb-server-core-10.1 (10.1.21+maria-1~yakkety) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket socat wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../12-socat_1.7.3.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von socat (1.7.3.1-1) ...
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-F7lK7w/06-libmysqlclient18_10.1.21+maria-1~yakkety_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If I uninstall mariadb (with `sudo apt sudo apt purge mariadb-client-10.1autoremove -f && sudo apt purge mariadb-common && sudo apt purge mariadb-client-10.1`), and look for anything left with `sudo dpkg -l | grep mariadb`, nothing is displayed, so I assume that MariaDB is uninstalled.

For safety, I did `sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoremove` afterwards, which seems to work fine. If I repeat the installation, the process above appears again.

Has anyone the same error, or did someone manage to install mariadb 10.1 on Ubuntu 16.10 and sees my mistake?

Comment: It appears that you still have `libmysqlclient18` installed at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the hint of @Jos, I could solve it:

`dpkg -l | grep mysql` returned

```
reichelt@reichelt-ThinkPad-T440s:~$ dpkg -l | grep mysql
rc  akonadi-backend-mysql                                 4:15.12.3-0ubuntu6                               all          MySQL storage backend for Akonadi
ii  libmysql-java                                         5.1.39-1                                         all          Java database (JDBC) driver for MySQL
rc  libmysqlclient18:amd64                                5.6.30-0ubuntu0.15.10.1                          amd64        MySQL database client library
rc  libmysqlclient18:i386                                 5.6.30-0ubuntu0.15.10.1                          i386         MySQL database client library
rc  libmysqlcppconn7                                      1.1.3-5                                          amd64        MySQL Connector for C++ (library)
iU  mariadb-common                                        10.1.21+maria-1~yakkety                          all          MariaDB database common files (e.g. /etc/mysql/conf.d/mariadb.cnf)
iU  mysql-common                                          10.1.21+maria-1~yakkety                          all          MariaDB database common files (e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf)
rc  php5-mysql                                            5.6.11+dfsg-1ubuntu3.3                           amd64        MySQL module for php5
```

so for some reasons, libmysqlclient18 still had configuration files (both for i386 and amd64). After running `sudo apt purge libmysqlclient18:i386` and `sudo apt purge libmysqlclient18:amd64`, the installations just runs normaly.